# Rewrite Query Parameters without hardcoding all parameter names

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-parameters

I have some URL like this:

> https://whatever.com/admin/members?keyword=Test&anotherparam=paramvalue

I want to have a URL like this:

> https://whatever.com/admin/members/keyword/test/anotherparam/paramvalue

I could accomplish this goal by hardcoding every rewriterule with every parameter name combination I will use in the whole project. But this is, in my opinion, a bad style and very cumbersome. I am a programmer. I am lazy. I want to have it more dynamically.

How can I rewrite the URL getting dynamically the passed query parameters? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this :

```
function changeUrl(string $url): string {
  $urlDetails = parse_url($url);

  if (!isset($urlDetails['query'])) {
      return $url;
  }

  parse_str($urlDetails['query'], $result);

  $newQueryString = '/';
  foreach ($result as $parameterName => $parameterValue) {
      $newQueryString .= $parameterName . '/' . $parameterValue . '/';
  }

  return str_replace( '?' . $urlDetails['query'], $newQueryString, $url);
}
```

It is an example if I understood well what you wanted.
Maybe you can add a validation on the $result variable too to make it more secure.

Comment: The key with this answer is that you are using application code for your routing instead of server rewrite rules. This is ultimately going to be much better. You will find that instead of creating a new query string, you just need to slice up the url into key/value pairs and then call the correct function.

Comment: Well I generally use the routing system provided by the framework the project is created with but here, I just answered the question with a small homemade function as I don't know if any framework is used or the context of using it